# Magento footer no style

Tags: html, css, magento, footer

For a couple of months now the footer (as well as some other minor things) on my Magento website (http://bestwheeldeals.com/) has lost its styling, I have looked at all the files that include footer background and nothing seems to be out of whack. It looks like that throughout the whole website. Also, on the home page where it says "Featured Wheels" there should be arrows to move past the products, if you hover next to the last image you can see that there's something there that's not being displayed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the style.css:

```
    html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, em, img, strong, ol, ul, li, table, tr, th, td, form { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; background: transparent; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
input, button{ overflow: visible; }
html, body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
body { font: normal 11px/14px tahoma, arial, verdana, sans-serif; text-align:center; color: #333; background: #f6f6f6; }
p { padding: 0 0 10px; }
ul { padding: 0 0 0 16px; }
li { padding: 0 0 8px; }
a  { text-decoration: none; }
a:link, a:visited { color: #1d64c1; }
a:hover, a:active { color: #6687dd; text-decoration: underline; }
.clear, .box .content { display: inline-block; }
.clear:after, .box .content:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
* html .clear, * html .box .content { height: 1%; }
.clear, .box .content { display: block; }
.none, .hidden { display: none; }
.page { position: relative; width: 100%; min-width: 750px; min-height: 100%; }
* html .page { height: 100%; min-height: 100% }
.page .header { width: 100%; height: 53px; text-align: left; background: #363b47 url('../img/common/top_bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x; }
.page .header .company-logo { float: right; display: block; margin: 6px 10px 0 0; width: 115px; height: 38px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999px; background: transparent url('../img/common/def_parallels_logo.gif') 0 0 no-repeat; }
.page .header .header-area { height: 53px; }
.page .header h1 { float: left; width: 156px; height: 49px; text-align: left; }
.page .header h1 a { display: block; width: 210px; height: 49px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999px; background: url('../img/common/def_plesk_logo.gif') no-repeat; }
.page .header .header-text { float: right; font-size: 11px; }
.page .header .header-text a { float: left; margin: 11px 13px 0 0; color: #506cc6; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; }
.page .header .header-text a.txt-banner { margin-right: 10px; }
.page .header .header-text a strong { font-weight: normal; }
.page .header .header-text a.top-copyright { text-align: right; }
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto; padding: 24px 0 50px; width: 734px; text-align: left; }
#body { margin: 0 auto; padding: 24px 0 57px 0; width: 734px; text-align:left;  }
.box { position: relative; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; width:100%; }
.box .content { padding: 10px; position: relative; }
.box em { display: block; width: 11px; height: 11px; position: absolute; background: url('../img/common/box-corners.png') no-repeat; overflow: hidden; }
.box em.tl { background-position: 0 0; left:-1px; top:-1px;}
.box em.tr { background-position: -29px 0; right:-1px; top:-1px;}
.box em.bl { background-position: 0 -29px; left:-1px; bottom:-1px;}
.box em.br { background-position: -29px -29px; right:-1px; bottom:-1px;}
.globe { float: left; background: url('../img/common/globe.png') 0 0 no-repeat; width: 167px; height: 198px; margin: 0; }
.welcome { padding: 0 0 0 187px; }
h2 { margin: 5px 0 10px; padding: 10px 0 3px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; color: #000; }
h3 { margin: 10px 0 5px 0; }
.hr { border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0; margin-top: 5px; padding: 10px 0 0; overflow:hidden; }
.center { text-align: center; }
.products { width: 390px; float: right; }
.new-to-parallels { width: 330px; float: left; }
.column { width: 180px; }
.column.left { float: left; }
.column.right { float: right; }
.column strong { display: block; margin-bottom: 11px; }
.column p { display: block; margin-top: 15px; font-size: 10px; }
.column img { float:left; margin-right: 15px; width: 69px; }
.page .footer { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; border-top: 1px solid #c0c7fc; width: 100%; min-width: 300px; height: 38px; background: #d9e9ff url('../img/common/footer_bg.png') 0 0 repeat-x; }
.page .footer-area { height: 38px; font-size: 11px; text-align: left; color: #000000; }
.page .footer .description { margin: 0; padding: 12px 10px 0; }
.icons-area { padding: 5px 10px 10px; text-align: center; background: url('../img/common/blocks_bg.png') 0 100% no-repeat; }
.icon { display: -moz-inline-box; display: inline-block; margin: 0 3px 12px 0; padding: 0; min-height: 32px; font: normal 11px/13px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; color: #000; cursor: pointer; background-position: 50% 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
a.icon:link, a.icon:visited, a.icon:hover, a.icon:active { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
.icon span { display: block; padding: 34px 0 0; width: 80px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; }
#asp { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_asp_bg.gif'); }
#aspnet { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_aspdotnet_bg.gif'); }
#coldfusion { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_coldfusion_bg.gif'); }
#perl { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_perl_bg.gif'); }
#php { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_php_bg.gif'); }
#python { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_python_bg.gif'); }
#ssi { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_ssi_bg.gif'); }
#fcgi { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_fast_cgi_bg.gif'); }
#miva { background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_miva_bg.gif'); }
.test { width: 680px; }
.test .pathbar { color: #7b7b7b; }
.test .pathbar a { text-decoration: underline; color: #7b7b7b; }
.test .pathbar a:hover { color: #39f; }
.test h2 { margin: 10px 0; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; }
.test .tab-content { border: 1px solid #a0b0e9; padding: 10px; background: #fff; }
iframe { border: 1px solid #a0b0e9; }
fieldset { border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px; }
legend { margin: 0; padding: 0 2px 5px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; color: #000; }
.form-fields { padding-top: 6px; }
.formFields { margin: 5px 0; }
.formFields, .formFields input, .formFields select, .formFields textarea { font: normal 11px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.formFields td.name { padding: 0 10px 10px 0; width: 200px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold; }
.buttonsContainer { margin-top: 10px; text-align: right; }
.buttonsContainer .commonButton { display: inline; margin-left: 14px; }
.buttonsContainer .commonButton span { display: none; }
.buttonsContainer .commonButton button { border: 0; width: 91px; height: 21px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer; font: normal 11px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: transparent url('../img/glyph/btn_bg.gif') 0 0 no-repeat; }
.commonButton button[disabled] { color: #999; background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_bg-disabled.gif'); }
#bid-ok button  { padding-left: 8px; background-image: url('../img/glyph/btn_ok_bg.gif'); }
.commonButton button:hover { background-position: 0 -21px; }
.commonButton button[disabled]:hover { background-position: 0 0; }
.testRelults#testFailed { border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 32px; background: #fde9e5 url('../img/icons/fail.gif') 10px 11px no-repeat; }
.testRelults#testSuccessful { border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 10px 32px; background: #bff7b4 url('../img/icons/success.gif') 10px 11px no-repeat; }
.testResult { font-weight: bold; }
.test-data { text-align: left; background: #fff; }
.test-data table { border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; color: #000; background-color: white; }
.test-data table th, .test-data table td { padding: 4px 6px; }
.test-data tr.subhead { background-color: #e8f4fe; }
.test-data tr.subhead th { border-bottom: 1px solid #b1c1f9; background: #e8f4fe url('../img/common/th-na-bg.gif') 0 0 repeat-x; }
.test-data th.alt { border-top: 1px solid #b1c1f9; border-bottom: 1px solid #b1c1f9; color: #000; background-color: #dbebff; }
.test-data tr.alt { background-color: #ebf4ff; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well you have a reference to `http://img.gostorego.com/media/s4dcb7132e9036/home_page/footer-back.gif` which doesn't load..

Comment: @NickR How can I check where that's at? It's not in the style CSS

Comment: I found it in the `net` tab in Firebug - https://getfirebug.com/ Although your webhost seems to be incredibly slow. There are a few files that just never load.

Comment: @NickR Thank you, I guess the person that created our site hosted the images there and the site went down. I found it and fixed it, thanks again! Now I'll just change all the images that were hosted on there.

Answer (score 0):

in the footer area, it doesn't seem to be using styles.css.  Rather, http://bestwheeldeals.com/media/css/8c4892c6843b806445f92ad78cea7d5a.css
line 7290 is overriding the bg image that line 6158 is trying to load.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have used multiple CSS in your projects. Please look one of your CSS, you have following code. Remove this block

```
.footer {
    background:none;
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

To able to which CSS file has above block, disable Magento's CSS merge option. (Admin -> System -> Config -> Developer -> CSS Settings, Do no to Merge CSS Files)

Comment: You see the background:none; This is main line that override your background. Also point the background image http://bestwheeldeals.com/skin/frontend/default/bwd/images/bkg_footer.png doesn't exist in path